# Using preg_match to find all words in a list

Tags: php, preg-match

With help from SO, I was able to pull a 'keyword' out of an email subject line to use as a category.  Now I've decided to allow multiple categories per image, but can't seem to word my question properly to get a good response from Google.  preg_match stops at the first word in the list.  I'm sure this has something to do with being 'eager' or simply replacing the pipe symbol `|` with something else, but I just can't see it.
    `\b(?:amsterdam|paris|zurich|munich|frankfurt|bulle)\b` .

The whole string I'm currently using is:

`preg_match("/\b(?:amsterdam|paris|zurich|munich|frankfurt|bulle)\b/i", "." . $subject . ".", $matches);`

All I need to do is pull all of these words out if they are present, as opposed to stopping at amsterdam, or whatever word comes first in the subject it's searching.  After that, it's just a matter of dealing with the $matches array, right?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Try `preg_match_all` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php - just add `_all` to the function name.

Comment: I would also add that the `$matches` changes a bit with `preg_match_all`

Comment: Thanks much!  And yes, $matches does change.  Now appears to be an array within an array, at first glance.  `print_r($matches)` gives me `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => paris [1] => bulle ) )` .  I'm looking into it, but any obvious suggestions for dealing with this?

Comment: Thanks again for the help @hakre and @datasage.  Don't know if it's 'proper', but I got it to work with a nested foreach loop.

Comment: Mark, I've added an answer with some more example code. Only adding _all was a bit short as datasage did correctly mention because of the changed values in `$matches`. The example shows how to convert the result into a simple array of cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here some example code with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) that shows how to remove the nesting as well:

```
$pattern = '\b(?:amsterdam|paris|zurich|munich|frankfurt|bulle)\b';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

# Check for errors in the pattern
if (false === $result) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Regular Expression failed: %s.', $pattern));
}

# Get the result, for your pattern that's the first element of $matches
$foundCities = $result ? $matches[0] : array();

printf("Found %d city/cities: %s.\n", count($foundCitites), implode('; ', $foundCities));
```

As `$foundCities` is now a simple array, you can iterate over it directly as well:

```
foreach($foundCities as $index => $city) {
    echo $index, '. : ', $city, "\n";
}
```

No need for a nested loop as the `$matches` return value has been normalized already. The concept is to make the code return / create the data as you need it for further processing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra help!  That clears things up a lot for me.  I knew there was a proper way to do that.