# How to determine if a sentence is talking about a specific subject?

Tags: php, nlp

I have predefined words and would like to know if the sentence primary subject is about the predefined words.

Example:

Predefined words:
iPhone, Nexus, HTC

Sentence:

I like the new design of iPhone - primary subject is iPhone

I am listing to Nirvana on my Nexus. - primary subject is not in predefined words

The HTC phone is better than iPhone - primary subject is HTC

Would like to do this in PHP or something I that can have PHP interface.

Comment: Just try to it myself but unsuccessful

Comment: Unless you want to try to implement a grammar for the English language, the best you can hope for is a "Contains" match.  Anything else wouldn't be much more than an approximation.  Try considering all of the possibilities of how you can designate the subject of an English sentence. -Edit- Yes, this is a defeatists approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias-i has a [natural language parser for PHP](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/demos.html).

Edit: [this page](http://www.akshatsinghal.com/content/natural-language-processing-php) says Alias-i's parser is written in PHP, but Alias-i's website says it is written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The short version: By Keywords.

This method works only with a limited set of Keywords.

A related question might be: [Using preg_match to find all words in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6351190/367456)

The long version: By parsing the language and making the computer system understand it.

The later is something linguists do. They develop such systems and it takes years. Probably you find some implementations available, but I do not know any from memory. Would need to ask a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get goog heurstic and evaluate them.
Examples:
1. Keyword is at beginning of sentence.
2. There are only one keyword in text.
3. Is there are continius form like "litenining" etc usaly leadt to subjective/uninformative message.

Write classifier upon those features. I would recommend Mallet.